# Перестали работать миграции Django

Tags: python, django

Каким то макаром очистилась папка migrations в моём Django приложении и теперь `manage.py makemigrations` пишет что изменений нет, хотя они есть... Как починить это дело?

Django 2.1 версия

Comment: Лучше всего восстановить папку migrations. Или очистить базу и создать миграции по новой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Сделать бэкап БД.
- Удалить БД
- Сделать makemigrations
- Применить миграции
- Сделать бэкап таблицы django_migrations
- Восстановить БД
- Восстановить таблицу django_migrations